# Summarizing SQL Tables

Tags: list-manipulation, sql

`data = Table[SQLSelect[conn, "All", {"col1", "col2"}, 
   SQLColumn["col1"] == n && SQLColumn["col2"] ==  o], {n, 1, 8}, {o, 21,
    30}];`

This results in selecting the range of data in each column specified. What I'd really like to do is get a count of *each* value in col1 *for each* value in col2. As it is, I will get:

{1,21},{1,22},{1,23},{1,24},{1,25},{1,26},{2,27},{1,23}...

If I use the complete range of values I just cull col1 and col2 from my original table.
What I have in mind is a table, per this example code, 8 rows x 9 columns that shows the count of all the times 1 and 21 appear together, then all the times 1 and 22 appear together up to 30, then how many times 2 and 21 appear and so on.

I want to end up with a table that looks something like this (row and column headers can be ignored):

```
     21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
1    1   1   2   7   12  30  47  80  91  112
2    1   1   3   12  18  48  59  118 133 151
```

and so on...

These SQL symbols are tricky in that they react strangely to variable manipulations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Search de docs for `Tally[]`

Comment: It might work if I could use that command directly on the table. I have a table with 9 columns and over 25,000,000 rows. I need to summarize statistics from this. It's food for thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will do yourself a service by doing as much as you can in SQL. In this case you can use

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY A,B
```

with `SQLExecute`. After that you have to use `GatherBy` to group them by the first element to get the kind of format you're looking for. But it's pretty easy.

So for this kind of query I would recommend asking/searching at Stackoverflow first for SQL based solutions.

I generated some test data like this:

```
data = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 8}, 1000], RandomInteger[{21, 30}, 1000]}];
```

And put up an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb6ae/3) to demonstrate the SQL query in action.

[image: fiddle]

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: The count is doubled. It appears to be counting col1 AND col2 in the total. I only want a tally of how many times col1 is a number as WHEN col2 is a certain value. I apologize if my original question wasn't clear. I guess I can just divide by two, but it concerns me that I do not have data integrity.

Comment: I am a novice at SQL and was hoping to avoid using it with MM, but MM cannot swallow by data set since it just doesn't handle large files well at all. If I change COUNT(*) to COUNT(col1) I am guessing I will get the desired result. I'll try it and comment again.

Comment: Changing the COUNT(col1) above is still counting everything twice. I need to keep things as simple as possible without having a workaround (remembering to divide by 2) in every piece of code that references this summary. Advice anyone?

Comment: @Sinistar I don't understand what you mean by counting it twice, there are several uneven numbes in the count column. This cannot happen if you count the same result twice.

Comment: My data set is known. There is only one value that 1 can be in column 1 and the value of column 2 be 21. There is only 1 for 22, and 3 for 24. When I run your suggestion on my actual data, I get 2, 2, 6 and this seems consistent as far as I have checked. I just want to know how many times the value 1, for example, appears when the other column is any value, say 88. But you see the actual data is 9 columns and 25 millions rows. This is an almost works solution. With you using random data, you'd never know you are getting twice the quantity, versus my known data which I know the shallow pool.

Comment: @Sinistar I'm sorry, I just cannot wrap my head around what you're trying to do. Probably just me being dumb. Please take a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08c52/1) minimal example and tell me what the result you expect is. If you need to you can construct your own data and tell me what the problem is. I think I will understand better with an actual example.

Comment: This data looks correct. For some reason the other query is doubling the expected count. For example, in my actual data the numbers 1 in the interesting column and 21 in the other interesting column only appear once, but the count comes up as two?

Comment: @Sinistar The query in my last example is the same as in the first one. It's just another data set. I'm afraid I cannot help you if you do not construct a data set which demonstrates the problem. Post it to SQLFiddle as I have with my data sets.

Comment: I wonder if this negative behavior is because I am running the query with SQLExecute?

Comment: @Sinistar No, `SQLExecute` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7be5a/2/0

Comment: Well it's kind of the only tool for the job to execute native SQL queries isn't it? I just wonder if there is some side effect. This is the first 30 lines of my data shown at the link above, the SQL query works as expected. It does not seem to when ran within the SQLExecute wrapper. in the first result for example, I get {1,21,2} and every other one I checked the count is twice as many as are in the table I query.

Comment: @Sinistar Which database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 Express using jDBC as middle man.

Comment: @Sinistar Maybe you should ask about this query on Stackoverflow and say that you're using this database. I haven't used it, but I'm sure this isn't a Mathematica problem. `SQLExecute` works but you need help from someone with knowledge about that flavor of SQL to find the best solution.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/440d0/1
I created and SQL Server 2012 schema in SQLFiddle. I copied your query and pasted it into my Fiddle. The query works. I am almost convinced now, there is something about the MM SQLExecute wrapper skewing my results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B, COUNT(A) OVER(PARTITION BY B) AS 'Count'
FROM DB.dbo.Table1
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY A, B
```

This is the query needed for Microsoft SQLServer 2012. This should work in versions back to SQL Server 2005, but was not tested. This correctly counts instances in the table where one value occurs with another value in a column. This would be similar in MM to using Position with Extract but this is easier, particularly because MM apparently chokes on files over 1GB so the database is pretty much required.